# Cannot run tests in androidTest module in kotlin multiplatform from android studio chipmunk

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, android-studio-chipmunk

Since upgrading Android Studio to Chipmunk, I seem to be unable to run tests from `androidTest` module.

It appears as if the classes that exist within `commonMain` are not accessible in `androidTest` yet they previously were in other versions.

I've also noticed that the `kotlin` directory is not green, which it would have been in other versions (even Bumblebee), despite the directory is marked as `Test sources root`

[image]

Has anyone else experienced, or has any suggestion on how to resolve? Im working away in Bumblebee just fine, but would like to eventually move over to Chipmunk

Comment: you have some 'compilation' or 'build' issue, can you show files inside androidTest/kotlin

Comment: Thanks @VadimEksler, the build issue is because I do not seem to have access to classes in `commonMain` module, despite the fact that they should be accessible, and are on previous versions of android studio